# Select2 - limit number of options

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2

> select2.github.io

As of now i am fetching option values from db and successfully i can see the options in the dropdown which on typing gets filtered.

***Expected:***

In case if my db have 1000's of option values i don't want to list all in dropdown.

So is it possible to either

- Limit the dropdown option to some number say 20 but the type search filter should filter from the whole db

(or)

- Hide the dropdown initially and when i type the filtered value will come as usual

if so kindly guide me on how to ?

Comment: It is only possible if you use ajax data to show up..
https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax